# How to listen for DatePicker date range changed

Tags: angular-material

Is it possible to listen for a *date range changed* event on the [Material Datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview)?

Currently, I use a workaround where I listen for `(dateChange)` for ***both*** start and end. Then I need to check that none of them are `null` and finally call my event handler `onRangeChanged(start: Date, end: Date)`.

From [full sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-datepicker-range-1?file=src/app/example-component.ts):

```
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Enter a date range</mat-label>
      <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="picker">
        <input matStartDate placeholder="Start date" (dateChange)="onStartDateChange($event)">
        <input matEndDate placeholder="End date" (dateChange)="onEndDateChange($event)">
      </mat-date-range-input>
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
    </mat-form-field>
```

```
  onStartDateChange(e: MatDatepickerInputEvent<Date, Date>) {
    if (e && e.value) {
      this.start = e.value;
    }
    this.checkRange();
  }

  onEndDateChange(e: MatDatepickerInputEvent<Date, Date>) {
    if (e && e.value) {
      this.end = e.value;     
    }
    this.checkRange();
  }

  checkRange(): void {
    if (this.start != null && this.end != null) {
      this.onRangeChanged(this.start, this.end);
    }
  }

  // Is it possible to have the DatePicker directly call this event handler?
  onRangeChanged(start: Date, end: Date) {
  }
```

Sidenote:

> In the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api) I
> found a *MatDateSelectionModel<S, D>* that potentially could give me a
> single *DateRange* at once, but I do not understand how to use it.

Comment: You are looking at an old version of the documentation (< v11.) That class is used internally and its dateChanged event can not be accessed developers.
See: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/21985

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, Andrew! I have now rephrased the side note to ask if the
publicly available type `MatDateSelectionModel<S, D>` returned by the function _registerInput_ can be used in any way.